# Play lottie file on button click

Tags: javascript, html, lottie

So I'm trying to create this little web game where when you press a button a Lottie animation should be played

This is what I've tried so far but it's not working for me, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<div id="hank"></div>

   <script>
       var menu = bodymovin.loadAnimation({ 
           container: document.getElementById('hank'), 
           renderer: 'svg', 
           loop: false, 
           autoplay: false, 
           path: 'hank.json',
        }) 
           
           document.getElementById('correctAnswer').addEventListener('click', function(){ menu.playSegments([0,180],true); })
</script>

<button id="correctAnswer"> Answer 1 </button>
<button> Answer 2 </button>
```

Comment: your js should go under the dom which it finds, or use domcontent/ready events before firing your js, check console for errors

Comment: Omg that fixed it bahaha i can't belive I didn't think of that, tysm!